# Uncaught Script Error for JS-Big-Decimal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I am new to JS and Node so I'm kind of confused with how importing modules work.  I am trying to import js-big-decimal into my project hosted on Google App Engine, and so I originally tried this:

```
var bigDecimal = require('js-big-decimal')
```

Which gave me an error.  I then tried this according to the requireJS documentation:

```
require(['require', 'js-big-decimal'], function (require) {
    var bigDecimal = require('js-big-decimal');
});
```

And I am now getting the error

```
require.js:1961 GET xxxxxxx.uk.r.appspot.com/js-big-decimal.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

and

```
require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "js-big-decimal"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1738)
```

According to the docs this is due to a syntax error or something somewhere, but I'm not sure where exactly that could even be.  What is the proper syntax for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Error's pretty self-explanatory... not a syntax issue (necessarily), but `xxxxxxx.uk.r.appspot.com/js-big-decimal.js` does not exist, it seems

Comment: I mean i have it installed in my node modules and my require call says its pointing to the place in which it's installed, so i dont know why that would be

Comment: Do you have js-big-decimal in your package.json dependencies?  See: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/specifying-dependencies and https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-big-decimal.  When you "require" that says you want to use it.  Adding it in the package.json makes it available for use.

Comment: Yes, both js-big-decimal and requirejs are listed

Comment: I replicated your issue and there's no problem on my end. Maybe it will help if you provide your whole code, directory structure or image, `package.json` and `app.yaml`.